# Awk output formatting

Tags: awk, gawk

I have 2 .po files and some word in there has 2 different meanings
and want to use awk to turn it into some kind of translator

**For example**

**in .po file 1**

msgid "example"

msgstr "something"

**in .po file 2**

msgid "example"

msgstr "somethingelse"

I came up with this

```
awk -F'"' 'match($2, /^example$/) {printf "%s", $2": ";getline; printf "%s", $2}' file1.po file2.po
```

The output will be

```
example:something example:somethinelse
```

How do I make it into this kind of format

```
example : something, somethingelse.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformatting

```
example:something example:somethinelse
```

into

```
example : something, somethingelse
```

can be done with this **one-liner**:

```
awk -F":| " -v OFS="," '{printf "%s:", $1; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i % 2 == 0)printf("%s%s%s", ((i==2)?"":OFS), $i, ((i==NF)?"\n":""))}'
```

**Testing**:

```
$ echo "example:something example:somethinelse example:something3 example:something4" | \
awk -F":| " -v OFS="," '{ \
printf "%s:", $1; \
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) \
    if (i % 2 == 0) \
       printf("%s%s%s", ((i==2)?"":OFS), $i, ((i==NF)?"\n":""))}'
example:something,somethinelse,something3,something4
```

**Explanation**:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{FS=":| ";OFS=","}      # define field sep and output field sep
{ printf "%s:", $1           # print header line "example:"
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)          # loop over all fields
    if (i % 2 == 0)          # we're only interested in all "even" fields
        printf("%s%s%s", ((i==2)?"":OFS), $i, ((i==NF)?"\n":""))
}
```

But you could have done the whole thing in **one go** with something like this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{OFS=","}                               # set output field sep to ","
NF{                                          # if NF (i.e. number of fields) > 0 
                                             #   - to skip empty lines -
   if (match($0,/msgid "(.*)"/,a)) id=a[1]   # if line matches 'msgid "something", 
                                             #   set "id" to "something" 
   if (match($0,/msgstr "(.*)"/,b)) str=b[1] # same here for 'msgstr'
   if (id && str){                           # if both "id" and "str" are set
       r[id]=(id in r)?r[id] OFS str:str     # save "str" in array r with index "id".
                                             # if index "id" already exists, 
                                             #   add  "str" preceded by OFS (i.e. "," here) 
       id=str=0                              # after printing, reset "id" and "str"
   }
}
END { for (i in r) printf "%s : %s\n", i, r[i] } # print array "r"
```

and call this like:

```
awk -f tst.awk *.po
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain the code that print everything out ?  It works perfectly fine, but I fail to understand the idea on how you do it.

Comment: I assume you mean the one-go one? Added some info just now.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, again thank you for your time :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'"' 'NR%2{k=$2; next} NR==FNR{a[k]=$2; next} {print k" : "a[k]", "$2}' file1 file2
example : something, somethingelse
```